# I want to center my <div> with css codes

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS and i have problems with positioning.
This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/simplex/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="main">
    <header>
      <h1 id="baslik">Dünyanın en iyi web sitesi!</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <p>Bu sitede bulacaklarınız:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Videolar</li>
        <li>Blog yazıları</li>
        <li>Eğlenceli şeyler...</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <footer>
      <p>Bu sitenin copyright hakları tarafımıza aittir.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
#main{
  text-align: center;
}
```

I cant align my text, how do i do this with HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

To horizontally center a block element (like div), use `margin: auto;`

Setting the width of the element will prevent it from stretching out to the edges of its container.

The element will then take up the specified width, and the remaining space will be split equally between the two margins.

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.center {
  text-align:center !important
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/simplex/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="main" class="center">
    <header>
      <h1 id="baslik">Dünyanın en iyi web sitesi!</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <p>Bu sitede bulacaklarınız:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Videolar</li>
        <li>Blog yazıları</li>
        <li>Eğlenceli şeyler...</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <footer>
      <p>Bu sitenin copyright hakları tarafımıza aittir.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  </body>
```

best to use a class when applying across many divs.

Comment: How do i can you explain with an example?

Comment: i used the class .center { text-align; center !important } and then add the center class to your main div. Run the code snippet. Clic on the the full page link to see all of the code. Cheers